# KeyError in Python **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Only the first print command works. I cannot figure out why. I want to display a different prefix and suffix depending on what is passed in.

```
# We are going to have a word and a prefix or a suffix before or after
# that word

def joinWords(string, **sFox):
    if sFox['prefix']: 
        return sFox['prefix'] + string
    elif sFox['suffix']: 
        return string + sFox['suffix']
    return string




#Why does this work?
#print(joinWords("Cookie", prefix="sugar"))

#And this does not?
#print(joinWords("Cookie", suffix="monster"))
```

Comment: change to  `def joinWords(string, **sFox):
    if sFox.get('prefix'): 
        return sFox['prefix'] + string
    if sFox.get('suffix'): 
        return string + sFox['suffix']
    return string`

Comment: `sFox[keyword]` will generate an error if the keyword does not exist, instead you should use `get()`, otherwise do not use elif since prefix and suffix are not mutually exclusive

Comment: `if sFox['prefix']` is not the correct way to check if the key exists.  If that is what you are trying to do, use `if 'prefix' in sFox` instead.

Comment: error is very much from begin false.  false is just a value, but error makes your program die.

Comment: Ok, I get it. It's like a variable that was never defined. Since I ran the function multiple times. It was checking for something that was not there in the particular command. Then an error resulted.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you're having is, `kwargs` will NOT contain keys that are not specified. When you try to index a non-existent key of a dictionary, it will raise a `KeyError`,

The most straightforward solution is to check if the key exists before trying to access it:

```
    if 'prefix' in sFox and sFox['prefix']:
```

There are also better Pythonic way to do this. As mentioned, `dict.get()` is a decent option for a default value:

```
    if sFox.get('prefix'):
```

This way, if `prefix'` is not in the dictionary, the value will be `None` which evaluates to boolean false and perfectly does the trick.

Of course, if you don't really need random keyword arguments, try default arguments:

```
def joinWords(string, prefix=None, suffix=None):
    if prefix:
        return prefix + string
    elif suffix: 
        return string + suffix
    return string
```

IMO this might be a better solution unless you're trying to learn about keyword argument packs.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing to a key that `sFox` does not have will raise an error.

Also, current code seems to only select the prefix even though suffix and prefix are both provided.

Looping through a `(key, value)` pair of the `sFox`, you might want to change your code as follows.

```
def joinWords(string, **sFox):
    for key, value in sFox.items():
        if key == 'prefix':
            string = value + string
        elif key == 'suffix':
            string = string + value
    return string
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use `sFox['prefix']`, It will raise key error when you don't pass key parameter prefix in  calling `print(joinWords("Tits", suffix="monster"))`.

To fix it you can use `sFox.get('prefix')`, it will return default None when you don't pass prefix keyword paramter.

Answer (score 1):

`sFox['prefix']` will return the item with key `prefix` in sFox if it exist, or else raise an `KeyError`.

Even worse, `if sFox['prefix']:` might still not execute your code even if `prefix` *does* exist in `sFox`, since `sFox['prefix']` might store the value `False`.

I think what you're actually trying to do with this line is to test if `sFox` *contains* an item with key `prefix`. In Python, the syntax `[key] in [dict]` is used for that.

Your program rewritten in it would look like this:

```
def joinWords(string, **sFox):
    if `prefix` in sFox:
        return sFox['prefix'] + string
    elif `suffix` in sFox:
        return string + sFox['suffix']
    return string
```

Now to answer your other question: Only the first part ever gets executed since you `return` in that part, i.e., leave the function. If you want both parts to execute, you must return only after you've added your suffixes and prefixes. Here's an example:

```
def joinWords(string, **sFox):
    if `prefix` in sFox:
        string = sFox['prefix'] + string
    if `suffix` in sFox: # Notice only "if" not "elif"
        string =  string + sFox['suffix']
    return string
```

Finally, to add a bit of syntactic sugar to the mix - take a look at [python default parameter values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values). With those you can define your function like this:

```
def joinWords(string, suffix="", postfix=""):
    return suffix + string + postfix
```